# Getting duplicate children in TouchXML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, touchxml

I have a CXMLDocument and the problem is that when I do this:

```
for (CXMLElement* auxitem in [doc children]){
    NSLog(@"NAME: %@", auxitem);
}
```

It gives me an empty CXMLNode and the CXMLElement with the information I want, like this:

```
2013-01-25 19:12:58.607 ClienteF[2438:c07] NAME: <CXMLNode 0x72ba5f0 [0x72ba900] text>
2013-01-25 19:12:58.607 ClienteF[2438:c07] NAME: <CXMLElement 0x72ba640 [0x72ba950] node        <node label="NAME" description="DESCRIPTION" id="1">
```

I only want to get the CXMLElement because it's the one with the information. How can I discard the CXMLNode? Of course I thought about get only the even numbers of the for but I'm looking for other alternative.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this:

```
for (CXMLElement* auxitem in [doc children]){
    if([[auxitem localName] isEqualToString:@"node"]){
        NSLog(@"NAME: %@", auxitem);
    }
}
```

Maybe it isn't the best solution but It works. Any idea more will be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following inside for loop :

```
CXMLNode *title = [auxitem nodesForXPath:@"the value" error:nil];
```